# Is there any environment variable that represents "C:\Documents and Settings" folder or C:\Users folder in Windows?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, javascript

Is there any environment variable or Other format that the profile path is represented in Windows? I want to query in such a way that I should get the value "C:\Documents and Settings (if windows XP or 2k3) or C:\users (If vista or windows 7).

I dont want the current user name appended to the string, which I can get thru %USERPROFILE% variable.

Comment: As you can put USER Profiles anywhere e.g. you could set mark up as c:\mark why do you need this and not USERPROFILE ? Also note the last directory is not necessarily the same as the user name.

Comment: Yes Mark.. What you said is true. I just want to know where a particular user profile is located? Also My environment doesn't 'redirect' these profiles other than default locations.

Answer (score 11):

It doesn't exist. Instead, try `%USERPROFILE%\..`

Warning: as @Mark suggests, this is not reliable because the user profile directory may really be any arbitrary location.

Comment: The %USERPROFILE% will append the current user name. I want to use it for a different username. I can still do it by some additional code in my script. But just want to know is there any better way to do it.

Comment: another user's profile directory is not necessarily %userprofile%\..\otheruser. But if you are sure it is, then yes you will have to whip it up in your script manually.

Comment: @svv: How do you know that the other user has their profile directory in a similar location?

Comment: Anon, As I mentioned above, my setup environment doesn't make any redirection for user profiles. They are just the windows default settings.

Answer (score 3):

On Vista+ you can use FOLDERID_UserProfiles to get C:\Users (or whatever it may be in localized versions, etc). On XP and earlier you'll pretty much have to go the CSIDL_COMMON_DESKTOPDIRECTORY route that will give you "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop" and work your way back from there.

I think this settles it for Vista. For XP the solution is not perfect, but at least it won't depend on the current user's profile path. "All Users" will always exist, and I can't think of a reason for it to be in a place other than the default.

Comment: I think the preferred method would be GetProfilesDirectory (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762278.aspx).

Comment: @Luke: Wow. How the heck did you pull that obscure API out of your head?

Comment: I always get a kick out of people's reactions to the existence of this function.  I guess since it is kind of isolated off into UserEnv instead of grouped with all the other path functions in Shell32 people tend to not know about it.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge no; but you can do a last instance of '/' to find the parent directory of `%USERPROFILE%`

Answer (score 1):

Yeah there actually is a way to get it to work:

```
%USERPROFILE%\..
```

Comment: downvoting because this answer adds nothing new to what tenfour has suggested. Please consider removing it

Answer (score 1):

I derived the batch and VBS methods (below), since I couldn't find an equivalent batch or VBS method for this question anywhere else. If I shouldn't add it to this thread (jscript), please add a comment on how/where it should go, and I will delete this answer and post as directed. :)

Batch (single line - no carriage return):

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%f in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" /v ProfilesDirectory ^|find /i "Profiles"') do @set ProfDir=%%g
```

VBScript:

```
' http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/registry/#ListRegFiles.htm

const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
strComputer = "."
Set StdOut = WScript.StdOut

Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &_
strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"
oReg.EnumValues HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath,_
 arrValueNames, arrValueTypes

For i=0 To UBound(arrValueNames)
'    StdOut.WriteLine "File Name: " & arrValueNames(i) & " -- "
    oReg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,_
    arrValueNames(i),strValue
'    StdOut.WriteLine "Location: " & strValue
'    StdOut.WriteBlankLines(1)
    IF arrValueNames(i) = "ProfilesDirectory" THEN ProfileRoot= strValue
Next

wscript.echo("ProfileRoot=" & ProfileRoot)
```