# is there any way to use GetProfilesDirectory in jscript?

Tags: javascript, user-profile

How can I use GetProfilesDirectory to retrieve c:\Documents and Settings or c:\Users (for vista and win7) in **Jscript**?

Or else any alternative way to get the user profile path (not of the current user) but for any given user in a Non-AD scenario.

Comment: Related: [Is there any environment variable that represents “C:\Documents and Settings” folder or C:\Users folder in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4504016/113116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `GetProfilesDirectory` function in JScript, because Windows Script Host doesn't support calling Windows API functions. However, you can get the profiles directory path from the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\ProfilesDirectory` registry value. Here's an example:

```
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var strProfilesDir = oShell.RegRead("HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\ProfileList\\ProfilesDirectory");
strProfilesDir = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(strProfilesDir);

WScript.Echo(strProfilesDir);
```

> Or else any alternative way to get the user profile path (not of the current user) but for any given user in a Non-AD scenario.

The abovementioned `ProfileList` registry key has subkeys corresponding to different users. The user's profile path is specified by the `ProfileImagePath` value of the appropriate subkey.